# Display text depending on the selected options

Tags: javascript, html

Note! Due to too much code full I write here: For test, here I paste full code: https://jsfiddle.net/j9efvnsk/

I've created simple dropdown.

```
  <label for="module-select">Wybierz instancje:</label><br />
      <select class="bootstrap-select" id="dropDownId" onchange="display()">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">WooCommerce</option>
        <option value="2">OpenCart</option>
        <option value="3">PrestaShop</option>
        <option value="4">Magento</option>
        <option value="5">WoordPress</option>
        <option value="6">Drupal</option>
        <option value="7">Joomla</option>
        <option value="8">Page Kit</option>
        <option value="9">WordPress Blog</option>
      </select>
```

Depending on the selected options in first dropdown, I displayed second dropdown with more options for selected value from first dropdown:

```
<div id="first">
        <label for="server-select">Wybierz typ instancji dla WooCommerce:</label>
        <form id="comment-form1" name="contact-form1" onsubmit="return mysubmit();">
          <select name="servers" id="optionswo">
            <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option value="https://myweb.com/app/index.php?rp=/store/woocommerce-ecommerce/wocommerce-ecommerce-own-template">Instancja z własnym szablonem (darmowa instalacja)</option>
            <option value="https://myweb.com/app/index.php?rp=/store/woocommerce-ecommerce/woocommerce-clean-instance">Czysta instancja WooCommerce (Dowolna wersja)</option>
            <option value="server3">Gotowy sklep WOS1 Kategoria: Sklep zoologiczny</option>
          </select><br /><br />
          <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="Zainstaluj" /><br>
        </form>
      </div>
```

For display second dropdown deepending on the selected option in first dropdown I use:

```
<script>
function display(){
    var e = document.getElementById("dropDownId");
    var index = e.selectedIndex;
    if(index==0){
        document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById("second").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("three").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("four").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("five").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("six").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("seven").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("eight").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("nine").style.display = 'none'
    }
    else if(index==1){
            document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("second").style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById("three").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("four").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("five").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("six").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("seven").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("eight").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("nine").style.display = 'none'
    }
</script>
```

(for easy test full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/j9efvnsk/ )
Current Result:

[image]

Issue:
Deepending on selected option in second dropdown I need display custom text (one text assigned to one option and text is different for every option).

Except result:
[image]

**For test, here I paste full code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/j9efvnsk/

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your related JavaScript code segment and then describe where in your code you're encountering an error or problem.  There are a ton of tutorials out there to demo How To conditionally show drop down elements.  It's expected you've at least tried to implement your requirements and aren't just asking us How To do it.

Comment: For test, here I paste full code: https://jsfiddle.net/j9efvnsk/  not possible add full code here in post.

Comment: Perhaps read what's [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) if you're not clear on what's wrong with your question.  There's also a link in that article which explains how to ask a good question.  In particular questions are expected to be about "a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Comment: @devlincarnate It still seems to me that this problem is artificially painted. Can you say my question is unclear to you and you are missing something to reproduce my mistake and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get values of selected option by attaching an event listener to `select`.

**P.S** - `DOMContentLoaded` event listener is for retrieving the selected value on first load.

```js
const countries = document.getElementById("countries");

const selectedValue = document.querySelector(".selected-value");

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  selectedValue.innerText = countries.value;
});

countries.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  selectedValue.innerText = event.target.value;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}
div p {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="countries">
    <option value="IN" selected>India</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
  </select>

  <p class="selected-value"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please check my live code here? https://jsfiddle.net/j9efvnsk/

Comment: Your jsfiddle code is super complicated!! I am not sure what you are actually tryna do

Comment: Please don't answer questions like this.  It encourages bad questions.  Either vote to close do to lack of details / debugging (an entire code dump is not "details") or vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @devlin why do you create problems for you? What's your problem? You dont need help? Please no write here.

Comment: I don't know what kind of man devlincarnate he is, he gives voty down. I ignore you man. Please leave this topic.    KunalTanwar thanks for your help. I apparance it.  Can you help us improve our code on: jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @JanKowalski My job is to help maintain the quality and integrity of this site.  Your job, when asking a question, is to show your best attempt in a **relevant** code segment, and then explain where you've encountered a problem or error in your code.  My comments aren't personal.

Comment: Where you see problem in my question? Sorry guy, but I not see any problem. I explain you, is not possible add full code in post that;s why I paste in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @JanKowalski - see my comment under your question.  We don't need your entire code.  We need your JavaScript code segment that shows your best attempt at implementing a cascading drop down, and then we need you to explain at what point in that code you aren't getting the results you expect.

Comment: I also try add full snippet code: not possible to do: https://prnt.sc/qq87uo9Vy7TN  "we need your JavaScript code segment that shows your best attempt" Okay, I try add some js code.